# How to pass JSON object using Ajax with ASP.NET WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, jquery

I have a problem with passing a JSON object using Ajax and ASP.NET WebMethods

```
function setStudentInfo() {
    var jsonObjects = [
        { id: 1, name: "mike" },
        { id: 2, name: "kile" },
        { id: 3, name: "brian" },
        { id: 1, name: "tom" }
    ];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ConfigureManager.aspx/SetStudentInfo",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: { students: JSON.stringify(jsonObjects) },
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result.responseText);
        }

    });
}
```

ASP.NET code

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SetStudentInfo(object students)
{
     //Here I want to iterate the 4 objects and to print their name and id
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> "{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: students.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()
>      at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)
>         at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
>            at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
>               at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)
>                  at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
>                     at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)
>                        at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}"

Comment: And what problem are you experiencing (more specifically)?

Answer (score 7):

I know its an old question but if someone gets here for an answer here's the solution;

```
var jsonObjects=[
    { id: 1, name: "mike" },
    { id: 2, name: "kile" },
    { id: 3, name: "brian" },
    { id: 1, name: "tom" }
];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ConfigureManager.aspx/SetStudentInfo",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({ students: jsonObjects }),
    success: function (result) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert(result.responseText);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 6):

Pass your entire JSON as a string, like this:

```
data: '{variable: "value"}'
```

I always get an error if I try to pass it as you have.

Comment: Keys need to be quoted also.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that error because a single Object is expected but your code is expecting a List of Objects. This can be a bit tricky sometimes. To make the data transfer easier, you should create a class with properties for the type of object you want to pass to the WebMethod, because it seems to be easier for ASP.NET to parse that. For example:

```
public class Student
{
    private string _name;
    private int _id;
    public string name {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    public int id {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
}
```

And then your WebMethod will change to accept a List of Student Class Objects, like so:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SetStudentInfo(List<Student> Students)
{
    foreach (Student s in Students)
    {
        //Do whatever here System.Console.WriteLine(s.name);
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is slightly change your Ajax call like so:

```
function setStudentInfo() {
    var jsonObjects = [
        { id: 1, name: "mike" },
        { id: 2, name: "kile" },
        { id: 3, name: "brian" },
        { id: 1, name: "tom" }
    ];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ConfigureManager.aspx/SetStudentInfo",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: { Students: JSON.stringify(jsonObjects) },
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result.responseText);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
function setStudentInfo() {

var jsonObjects = {"students" : [
    { id: 1, name: "mike" },
    { id: 2, name: "kile" },
    { id: 3, name: "brian" },
    { id: 1, name: "tom" }
]};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ConfigureManager.aspx/SetStudentInfo",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObjects),
    success: function (result) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert(result.responseText);
    }

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually sending json to the server, to send json just pass a json string for the data property.

```
data: JSON.stringify(jsonObjects),
```

Comment: when performing your change i am getting the following" "{"Message":"Type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]\u0027 is not supported for deserialization of an array.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, IList& convertedList

Comment: @user829174 I don't know much about asp.net but it looks like your webmethod is expecting an object and getting an array.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, to what should i change the signature of my method so i will be able to send that particular JSON object to the server, can you share a code?