# cannot send json or text to C# bhind-code using AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax

I have an AJAX code where I am trying to send some data to a method within C# code-behind

I've tried to send them either using text data type and json data type, but neither of them are working with me.

when I use json type, it returns me the following error:

> Internal Server Error

and when using text me
thod, there is no error appear and the code comes through the `success` function, but the actually the data is never sent to the method of the code-behind class

this is the ajax code using json type:

```
function searchClicked(sCriterion) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "TokenRegistration.aspx/GetSearchCritetrion",
            data: "{creiterion : " + sCriterion + " }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert("We returned: " + result);
            }
```

And this is the ajax code using the text format:

```
function searchClicked(sCriterion) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "TokenRegistration.aspx/GetSearchCritetrion",
            data: sCriterion,
            contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "text",
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert("We returned: " + result);
            }
```

Also here is the my code-behind method that the data should be sent to:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void GetSearchCritetrion(object selectedItem)
{
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var data = json.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>[]>(selectedItem.ToString());
}
```

I've used the exact same ajax code in another project and it works perfectly, but here i'm not getting where the error is, so any suggestions please?

Comment: try make the url `url: "/TokenRegistration.aspx/GetSearchCritetrion",`

Comment: it's not working dear, @Mostafiz

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13453161/6384980) help you.

```
class Item 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static void GetSearchCritetrion(Item selectedItem)
{
    //ToDo: selectedItem.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see if this works
instead of sending object try to pass as string

```
data: JSON.stringify({selectedItem : sCriterion }),
```

code behind

```
public void GetSearchCritetrion(string selectedItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really simple example that posts JSON to a controller method, which converts this into an object and then returns a response.

HTML:

```
<button id="go" class="btn">Go</button>
```

JS:

```
    var obj = { foo: 123, bar: "abc " };
    $('#go').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Test/TestJson',
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.result)
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert('fail');
            }
        });

    });
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
    public JsonResult TestJson(TestClass tc)
    {
        return Json(new { result = "foo=" + tc.foo + " bar=" + tc.bar }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public int foo { get; set; }
        public string bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```